# GoogleApiClient error with addApi(Plus.API) & addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)

Tags: android, google-api-client

I have an error in: `addapi(Plus.API);` plus is showing error and i don't know why.

I use the next code, given by Google, and the *"Plus"* doesn't exist.

```
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .build();

    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

The problem persist and i don't know what i'm making bad.

I configured the google-services.json file following the instruction by google. And i got the OAuth and the sha, for make the config file. And i don't find the answer to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you have not added the Google Play Services library in your app.
Add the following line in your app's build.gradle file

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.3.0'
```

Comment: worked, thanks, i delete too: //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.3.0'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:7.3.0'